# How do I include a gem's class method in a Rails model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I'm learning how to write a gem. I want to add some methods that I will use in a User model in Rails.

```
# app/models/user.rb
class User
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Authme::Model  # here's my gem.

  field :password_digest, type: String
end
# Gemfile
gem 'authme'
```

Now, inside my gem I have the following:

```
- authme
  - lib
    + authme
      - model.rb
    - authme.rb
```

Here are the contents of the gem.

```
# lib/authme.rb
require 'authme/version'
require 'authme/model'
module Authme
end

# lib/authme/model.rb
module Authme
  module Model
    extend ActiveSupport::Concern

    included do
      include ActiveModel::SecurePassword
      has_secure_password validations: false
      before_create :create_session_token
    end

    module ClassMethods
      def new_session_token
        SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64
      end

      def encrypt(token)
        Digest::SHA1.hexdigest(token.to_s)
      end
    end

    private

    def create_session_token
      self.session_token = self.class.encrypt(self.class.new_session_token)
    end
  end
end
```

I add this to my gemspec:

```
spec.add_dependency "activesupport", "~> 4.0.1"
```

To test this, inside the terminal, I tried `User.new_session_token` and got this error:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `new_session_token' for User:Class
```

What am I doing wrong? I really want to test this, but I'm out of my depth. I'm not sure how to test that the class User has the included the gem module.

Comment: did you defined path to your gem in Gemfile , and bundle update ?

Comment: I ran bundle update. As for defining a path, I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: if you want rails to pickup changes in your gem then you must define path in Gemfile for that gem . ex gem 'authme', path: /home/anil/path-to-gem

Comment: Thanks, but I don't think this is the issue. I've installed and uninstalled the gem each time I've made a change to it. I've bundled with Rails and with the gem. I think going something wrong with my code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you're creating `Authme::Model` and `Authme::Model::ClassMethods` but you're never actually adding `new_session_token` as class methods of `Authme::Model`.

If you want to add these methods onto `Authme::Model` you need to do something like

```
module Authme
  module Model
    module ClassMethods
      # define all of your class methods here...
    end

    extend ClassMethods
  end
end
```

The key part here is the [Object#extend](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Object.html#method-i-extend).